# no viable conversion from returned value of type 'std::bitset<3>' to function return type 'int'

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

bitmark.hpp

```cpp
class BitMark {
 public:
  using mark_t = std::bitset<2>;
  constexpr static mark_t A{0b00};
  static constexpr std::optional<mark_t> FromAsciiIdx(int c) {
    switch (c) {
      case 1:
        return A;
      default:
        return {};
    }
  }
};
```

run `/usr/bin/clang-tidy bitmark.hpp --checks='cppcoreguidelines-*'`

return `error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'const BitMark::mark_t' (aka 'const bitset<2>') to function return type 'int' [clang-diagnostic-error] return A;`

why? Is there an implicit conversion happening here? But I changed the return value to `std::bitset<2>{A}` and it still threw this error.my clang-tidy version is `15.0.7`.

Comment: Does this header have `#include <optional>`?

Comment: I found the reason for my error, since vscode kept throwing errors, I deleted all my build files and deleted `compile_commands.json`, when I tested with the command, `clang-tidy` was not in the root directory After reading this file, I relinked the file and now all the errors are gone

Comment: Sounds like you have the beginnings of an answer there, Elliot. You should formalize it and clean up the question to make the cause-and-effect connections between question and answer brutally clear to the next poor sucker who runs across this problem.

Comment: [clang 15.0.0 itself seems perfectly happy compiling it.](https://godbolt.org/z/M3bjqvdq5) as long as it has appropriate headers included.

Comment: This kind of error should be found in compilation time, so just compile it to check the error with `-Wall` should be enough since clang-tidy depends on `compile_commands.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to `compile_commands.json` in the root directory and ensure that it is the latest link. `clang-tidy` will read this file. As of the reply, I still have not found a way to correctly set the build-path in vscode.After I find it, I will reply to the setting method of vscode here.